# 'str' object has no attribute 'append' attribute error when i try append to dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, attributes, attributeerror

I'm a beginner programmer and this is my first post on this website.
I trying to append value to the existing key in the dictionary, but I keep getting attribute errors. I already tried append value to the existing key on another project and it worked perfectly. So I'm pretty much at a dead end.
I would really appreciate it if you guys can point out my mistake and help me to fix my code.

**Edit**::

After a few answers I think, I need to do a better explanation of what is my situation and what I what to achieve.

My situation is when I do my experiment I get around a hundred files from where I need to extract data (I will provide a few of them in the link below).

What I trying to achieve is to extract all the data from files in the folder and put it in one file something like .csv style. So I can import it more easily to Originlab(something like Excel).

I imagine my code will do something like this:

First file extracted:

```
0.9761
0.9793
0.9825
0.9852
0.9850
0.9861
0.9848
0.9881
```

Second file extracted:

```
0.9761 0.9850
0.9793 0.9756
0.9825 0.9751
0.9852 0.9765
0.9850 0.9753
0.9861 0.9803
0.9848 0.9856
0.9881 0.9864
```

and so on...

It could be separated by blank space or a comma.

The reason why I need multiple values on one key is that these numbers are values for the y-axis and all data set will have the same value on the x-axis.

Link for files:
[Share files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OcaOqt3jG7FxFxVWiA5vqN1LQYRYjbSd?usp=sharing)

**My code**:

```
import glob
import os

def main():

 direct = r"C:\Users\Inzaghi\Desktop\Ondra_origin"

 main_dict={}

 for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(direct, '*.spe')): 
  
    with open(filename,'r') as file:    
        print ('file read: ' + filename)
        lst=[]
        for line in file:
            line = line.replace('# ','')
            if len(line) == 14:
                line = line.rstrip().split()
                lst.append(line[1])
      
        for count, n in enumerate(lst[:-4]):
            if count in main_dict:
                main_dict[count].append(n)
            else:
                 main_dict[count]=n
                 
with open (direct+'\celkovy_file.txt','a') as f:
     for i in range(0,len(main_dict)):
         f.write(main_dict[i] + '\n')
print('Done')

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Strings cannot be appended .. Only lists..

Comment: `main_dict[count]=n` should be `main_dict[count]=[n]`

Comment: I suggest you use `collections.defaultdict()` or `maindict.setdefault()` so you don't need to check whether the key exists yourself.

Comment: `main_dict.setdefault(count, []).append(n)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
for count, n in enumerate(lst[:-4]):
    if count in main_dict:
        main_dict[count].append(n)
    else:
        main_dict[count]=n
```

to

```
for count, n in enumerate(lst[:-4]):
    main_dict.setdefault(count, []).append(n)
```

`dict.setdefault` method will set a default value to a key (in this case an empty list) if it isn't already in the dictionary. If it exists, the `append` method appends the iterating item to its corresponding value list.

Answer (score 0):

```
main_dict[count] += n
```

Should give you the desired result

Though that will make the values into a long string. If you want the values to be a list you could do:

```
       if count in main_dict:
            main_dict[count].append(n)
        else:
             main_dict[count]= [n]
```

Comment: Hello, I tried your suggestion but it still giving me an "Attribute error: 'str' object has no attribute 'append' ". 
I edited my post to better explain what it intended to do.